Magento 2.4.7 Minicart not showing any items
After Upgrade to Magento 2.4.7 ,
my Minicart stop showing products,
I check my overridden theme file :
app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html
and it was perfect not any tag is closed like this : "/>"
after some debug I found that this will not render :
<each args="$parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))"
                      render="{name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}}"></each>

this will not render the cart items I think !!
can anyone help me about this ?

Have you checked by switching to the default Magento theme blank/luma? Is it working fine there? If yes you have an issue with your overridden files.

@Mark Philips
Hey,
enter corename Magento_Checkout to Magento_Checkout--

at app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\ location

and run below command
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:fde here

And check minicart is load or not, if its not working please share the screenshot or the URL, so we can check from our end also.
Thank You!
